# Jquery: Page scraping, turn C# code to Jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have been working on some code to scrape data from a webpage using C#. Unfortunately after creating the code and getting it to work i noticed that the webpage i had to implement it on was using Jquery on the input my code was meant to be going on.

So now i have to change my code to work with Jquery. I was wondering if page scrapping is even possible in Jquery and if anyone could give me a hand?

I have found this code but have no idea if it will work as my Jquery skills are very bad.

p.s i am coding in ASP.Net web forms using C# codebehind

EDIT: it would also work if i could execute the current javascript from the code-behind

```
$.get("/path/to/other/page",function(data){
  $('#data').append($('li',data));
}
```

my C# code is

```
protected void GetAverageRent_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Postcode = _postCodeInput.Value.ToString();
                var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
                var doc = webGet.Load("http://www.webaddress.com" + Postcode);

                HtmlNode AvgPrice = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='split2r right']//strong[@class='price big']");

                if (AvgPrice != null)
                {
                    AverageRentLbl.Text = AvgPrice.InnerHtml.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    AverageRentLbl.Text = "Invalid Postcode!";
                    AverageRentLbl.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                    AverageRentLbl.Font.Bold = true;
                }
        }
```

Comment: Google like `using jQuery page method asp.net` and return the html data to your jQuery ajax call

Comment: thanks but that is a very ambiguous answer. I am not a l33t coder i am just a novice web designer

Comment: I have not given answer. Just a tip where you can look. Please try something first :)

Comment: Thanks i just looked it up and think i understand it but how will this help execute a Jquery script and codebehind at the same time? is this able to do that?

Comment: why you need to execute both at same time. Make a ajax call using jQuery and get your data and bind it

Comment: Basically when i enter a postcode then my page needs to call a google API in Jquery to geolocation/map and display it (this works atm) and then grab the average rent price for that area but this code is in C# (also works ATM) but how do i get them both to execute when the user enter the postcode. EDIT: sorry the google API is in javascript not Jquery :(